# How override loglevel from application.conf in sbt tests?

Tags: scala, logging, configuration, sbt, akka

I have sbt project with test here `application.conf` which is used in **tests** :

```
akka {
    loglevel=DEBUG
    #other settings
}
```

When I try to run `sbt clean test -Dakka.loglevel=INFO` I see debug statements in log. For example:

```
[DEBUG] [11/26/2014 11:47:44.328] [unit-test-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://unit-test/system/cluster/heartbeatReceiver] started  (akka.cluster.ClusterHeartbeatReceiver@11ee5ffb)
```

Is it possible to pass java options from command line to override settings in `application.conf`?

**UPDATED**

java version

```
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
```

scala version

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_71).
```

sbt version

```
0.13.5
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the order of the commands passed to the sbt

```
sbt -Dakka.loglevel=INFO clean test
```

Comment: Definitely it works correctly on latest sbt/scala/akka versions, what versions you are using?